# Inserting multiple values into database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Let's say I want to add the values from 2 different tables with an insert function.

I'll pass the tables' name as parameter, `address` and `city`, for example. But address has 3 columns and city has 4.

Is there any function or way to count the amount of columns in the insertion? This is kind my idea:

Add address -> `cur.execute("insert into {address} values (%s, %s, %s)")`

**OR**

Add city -> `cur.execute("insert into {city} values (%s, %s, %s, %s)")`

Comment: That's *columns*, not values you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks, already changed it.

Comment: Secondly, you must't have a mismatch anyway, so you can rely on your Python table to have the proper number of columns, so you can get the count as len() of the  Python table row.

Comment: In what form do you get the table name and the values to insert? In other words, is this a question about how to compose your query string or how to compose the values to replace in that string?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to query the metadata:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'address' AND table_schema = 'public';
```